# Selenium Credit Card module element not interactable

Tags: python, selenium, http, automation

I am trying to automize checkouts on this website: https://en.aw-lab.com.
Now I am trying to pay by finding each input path of the creditcard module but I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send_keys
```

.
This means that the element cannot be found and hence the send keys is not possible. Now my question is, how can I acces this element?

I have tried finding the name on card element by both the ID and the xpath but the error is still present. I have also tried adding a sleep before finding the element so the page could be fully loaded, but this did not solve the problem.

```
time.sleep(2)
cardname = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="cardOwner"]')
cardname.send_keys(ccname_input)
```

Other posts have mentioned to go into the iframe but this page does not have an iframe.
Another post says that the script is generated by javascript: I tried that code aswell but than I get a error `element not interactable`.

```
    inputCC = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(
    lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="cardOwner"]')
)
inputCC.send_keys(ccname_input)
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
//input[@id="cardOwner"]
```

Select the input with that id and not the div.